# Arcpy - Loop through a feature class and create Euclidean Distance for every feature

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I am trying to use SearchCursor to loop through a feature class and create a Euclidean Distance raster dataset for every feature in that feature class. This ED raster dataset will be used for further analysis. However, I got this error message which I cannot solve. Can anyone explain or help please.

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(Tank_Location_Data)

for row in cursor:

    arcpy.gp.EucDistance_sa(row, "50", "1", "#")
```

Error message:

```
arcpy.gp.EucDistance_sa(row, "50", "1", "#")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 498, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Comment: What is your distance range?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd recommend using the search cursor in the data access module, [**`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) instead of the one you are using.  It's much more efficient.

Secondly, the [**Euclidean distance**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-distance.htm) tool doesn't work on individual rows of a dataset.  You'll have to create a feature class for each record. You can do this by creating a temporary feature layer for each record. Try **[MakeFeatureLayer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm)**.

Comment: I already tried to MakeFeatureLayer for each record before the Euclidean Distance command. But I got this error message instead: _arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(row, "row_lyr")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6043, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool_

Comment: Try running it again with just the shape. You can do that with the da.SearcgCursor

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the incorrect modules in your code.

First off, you need to switch over to the Data Access module for cursors - arcpy.da.SearchCursor:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/what-is-the-data-access-module-.htm

You don't have to switch, but the da cursors perform better.

Second, the current method to call Euclidean Distance is to import arcpy.sa and then use this syntax:

> EucDistance_sa (in_source_data, {maximum_distance}, {cell_size}, {out_direction_raster}, out_distance_raster)

You will also need to check out the spatial analyst extension in your script unless you are running from ArcMap with the extension already checked out.

Docs:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-distance.htm

Comment: Please be aware the OP is asking about ArcGIS 10.2 but all of your documentation links to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I am using 10.2

Comment: @Midavalo - if you had checked, you would see that it is same details on the ArcMap page vs Pro https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-distance.htm vs https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/euclidean-distance.htm

Comment: @jbalk That may be true for now, but ArcGIS Pro is a work in progress, and unlike previous versions of ArcMap, the help is updated with the application rather than separate documentation for each version so it has potential to change